# Are eShop download "game-saves" saved to your SD card?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf, nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds

Once a game is downloaded from the eShop, is the game save saved on the SD card or the console?

If it's saved on the SD card, can it be loaded by the same game on a different console?

I'm wondering if I could keep a back up copy of my Animal Crossing game save incase something goes wrong with the console etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The game save is located on the SD card. If you have the same SD card and the same account on a different console it should work

Comment: So if I downloaded Animal Crossing on a new System from the same Club Nintendo account and used my old SD card, it would load the game up?

Comment: Yes, that is how it works.

Comment: say you upgrade to a bigger SD card. just copy 'n paste all of your content from your old SD to your new SD, and all of your save files and downloaded games will still be intact and usable, right?